# Changing data-value when Clicked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

value when clicked tried these codes but when i inspect the elements the value is not changing

```
<div id="foo" data-value="3">Click Here</div>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
$("#foo").on('click', function(){
  var foo1 = $(this);
  var c = foo1.attr('data-value');
  var sum = parseInt(c) + parseInt(3);
  $("#foo").data("data-value", sum);
});
```

Comment: Which browser are you inspecting with? In older versions of Internet Explorer, the page source does not dynamically change.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132(64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the attribute value you can use `attr`, like you get the attribute value with `attr`. Try the following:

```js
$("#foo").on('click', function(){
  var foo1 = $(this);
  var c = foo1.attr('data-value');
  var sum = parseInt(c) + parseInt(3);
  a = foo1.attr("data-value", sum);
  console.log(foo1.attr("data-value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo" data-value="3">Click Here</div>
```

Comment: It's better to use `foo1` where you are using `$(this)`

Comment: thank you very much.. this works..i tried the attr() recently but nothing happened.. and i copied your codes and it works..